# Get hold of Foo[].class given Foo.class

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I have an object, `c`, of type `Class` (I get hold of the object in runtime so I can't tell in compile-time which class it represents.)

Suppose `c` represents the class `Foo`. I now want to get hold of a `Class`-instance which represents `Foo[]`.

How is this done best using the standard Java API?

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a simple example of your intention, it's not very clear from the question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77387/how-to-instantiate-a-java-array-given-an-array-type-at-runtime

Comment: yes the above will work - but if you need to do that - in majority of case you have a badly designed application (i.e. polymorphism usually handles everything you need the right way)

Comment: I'm developing something similar to a compiler and the particular use case is quite complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html, one of the ways is:

```
Class arrayClass = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, 0).getClass();
```

This looks like a cheat, but it's definitely cleaner than playing with the class *names*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
public class ReflectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo c = new ReflectTest().new Foo();
        Foo[] foos = (Foo[]) Array.newInstance(c.getClass(), 5);
    }
    class Foo {
    }
}
```

Comment: `c` is of type `Class` in my question... but I see what you're aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in my test, this should work:

```
Class c = ...
Class cArr = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(c, 1).getClass();
```