# J2ME BlackBerry creating instance from array class

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, java-micro-editon-sdk3.0

Is there a way to create an array from a `Class` object dynamically using something like

```
MyClass[].newInstance();
```

I'm aware that it throws an  `InstantiationException`, but is there a way for me to instantiate an array indicating its type with a `Class` object?

Comment: Could you clarify? Sounds like you want an array where the type can be set/changed. Which I don't think is possible. Closest I can think of is `Object [] array = new MyClass[10];`

You could maybe use that idea and make a class that copies/casts objects in an array to another type.

Comment: related?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1632130/813951

Comment: For the first comment: I don't know the class, (i's a variable of the type class). For the second comment: I'm using J2ME. Bottom line, is not posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77474/119114) is not available in J2ME, I think you'd need a loop to do this for each object:

```
private Object[] createArray(String fullClassName, int length) {
    Object[] objects = new Object[length];
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(fullClassName);
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            objects[i] = c.newInstance();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objects;
}
```

and remember to fully-qualify the name (if you're using stringified class names):

```
  Object[] array = createArray("mypackage.Widget", 10);
```

with

```
package mypackage;

public class Widget {
    public int foo() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Note that the [getConstructor() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) is not available in the [BlackBerry Class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/index.html?net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html), so you're limited to creating objects with **no-argument constructors.**

Comment: Using the stringified name of the class is the solution here. But only if I'm using a concrete class, if the array is abstract or an interface, there is no way to get the array component typeto instantiate those.

Comment: @danielrvt-sgb, you don't have to use string names if you don't want to.  In my example, you can change `createArray()` to take `Class c` as a parameter.  But, **somewhere**, you will need to decide to create a **concrete** class.  You cannot instantiate abstract classes, or interfaces.  Something will have to decide which subclass of an abstract class, or which implementation of an interface will be created.

Comment: Also, please remember to vote for answers that are useful.  Questions like these don't get much attention, and voting is the way to identify answers that work.  Thanks.